# como hacer peticiones desde ajax a python y sqlite

Tags: python, html5, ajax, python-3.x, sqlite3

hola amig@s tengo una duda la cual pues no se que es lo que debo usar, soy nuevo en la programación web y ya se lo suficiente para hacer una página web, lo que sucede es que quiero hacer una App y usando un compilador de código como cordova el cual me permite crear una App con html5 css3 y javascritp, pero yo quiero hacer la App usando una base de datos sqlite3, se usar php para interactuar con la base de datos y ajax, pero para usar php necesito un servidor de apache si no me equivoco, entonces no puedo usar php en una App , porque la App lo necesito para que funcione sin internet osea que sea independiente de la web y es por eso que quiero usar sqlite3, mi problema es que no se que lengueje usar para interactuar con la base de datos desde el móvil.

Se usar un poco python y ya que python3 hace muchas cosas entre ellas interactuar con la base de datos sin la necesidad de un servidor de apache, corrijan-me si me equivoco, entonces quisiera saber si voy por buen camino, usar html5, css3, jquery, ajax, python3 para interactuar con la base de datos sqlite3, puedo hacer eso? ¿ si es posible?, como hago las peticiones desde ajax a python3 como si fuera php.

disculpe mi ignorancia y es por eso que formula esta pregunta para que me ayuden, estaré muy agradecido de sus respuestas y concejos.

Comment: si quieres usar sqlite no necesitas python basta con js.

Comment: ¿puedo acceder a datos sqlite solo con js? me podrías dar un ejemplo o alguna parte donde se explique como hacerlo.

Comment: use node.js http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/

Comment: gracias voy a ponerme a estudiar

Comment: una pregunta más,¿ todo esto se hace con javaScript?

Comment: Sí, ¿por qué tu duda?

Comment: es que estoy tratando de hacer la conexión  con una base de datos sqlite pero me da error lo estoy haciendo como indica en el ejemplo que esta en la página que me enviaste, ya descargue el modulo. si no es mucha molestia me podrías mandar un ejemplo de conexión con una base de datos sqlite.

Comment: alli esta el ejemplo, no sé que más deseas, decir *me da error* no es muy util si deseas ayuda.

Comment: claro dice que   "require is not defined"

Comment: ¿sabes usar node.js?, me parece que no tienes instalado node.js o no lo has iniciado, te recomiendo buscar otro tutorial ya que node.js instala un servidor.

Comment: ah jeje es que se estaba instalando en la carpeta principal, y el js estaba en una carpeta secundaria, me faltaba moverme asta ella antes de instalar, jeje errores de novatos. listo gracias.